# How to trigger parent's function?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function someFunction () {
  alert('fired!')
}
var options = [
  {selector: 'footer', offset: 50, callback: 'someFunction()' },
];
Materialize.scrollFire(options);
```

I'm getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: someFunction is not defined`

I do understand why it happens, but i can't get, how should i trigger someFunction anyway?

ps. if i change `'someFunction()'` to `alert('fired!')`, alert happens.

Comment: It means that `someFunction` is not accessible. Can you post entire code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change it to a reference to the function:

```
var options = [
  {
    ...
    callback: someFunction
];
```